# Word choice and usage

Tags: word-usage

Can I today use the word 'thrice' or is it completely out of date and shouldn't be used?
Dusan

Answer (score 0):

I read the NY times daily, and subscribe to Foreign Affairs magazine and study discourse, and I've yet to see the use of "thrice" so I would say it's outdated.

Answer (score 0):

I like the word and use it.  But I'm out on a limb it seems.

https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=thrice%2C+three+times&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cthrice%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthree%20times%3B%2Cc0